# make option --what-if consider also other outdated files

Tags: gnu-make

I'm trying to get the list of targets that depends on a single file.
The "--what-if" option of make seems to do the job, but I'd like to ignore any other outdated files, except the one I'm giving as argument.

This is my test case (working on debian with gnu make 4.0):

$ cat makefile

```
all: exe1 exe2 

exe1: obj1
    echo "a" > exe1

exe2: obj2
    echo "b" > exe2

obj1: src1
    echo "c" > obj1

obj2: src2
    echo "d" > obj2
```

$ make

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

$ make -n -W src1

```
echo "c" > obj1
echo "a" > exe1
```

Perfect. This is the answer I want: modifying src1 causes exe1 to be rebuilt.

But if I change the other file "src2"...

$ **touch src2**

$ make -n -W src1

```
echo "c" > obj1
echo "a" > exe1
echo "d" > obj2
echo "b" > exe2
```

So make is "making" also "exe2".
Is there a way to tell make to ignore any other outdated file?
In this case, I'm not interested to know that "exe2" would be rebuilt since it does not depends on the file "src1".

In other words, I'm looking the answer to this question: "What targets depends upon src1?"

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You are executing the first rule in your makefile per default, which depends on exe1 and exe2, i.e. you get what you told make is that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of what options you give to `-W`, make will always try to build the standard set of targets (the "goal targets").  `-W` has no impact on the selection of goal targets.

If you want make to build one a specific target, then you give that target on the command line.  So, if you want to only have make build `exe1` but not `exe2`, you would run `make exe1`.

So to do what you want you combine these features:

```
make -n -W src1 exe1
```

If you want to assume that `src2` is not new you can use the `-o` option:

```
make -n -o src2 -W src1
```

Comment: The purpose of my command is to know what targets would be rebuilt when "src1" changes... I can't specify any target on the command line.
In other words, I'm looking the answer to this question: "What targets depends upon src1?"

Comment: So, what you're really asking is there a way for make to be told to assume that all files are updated except one file, regardless of reality.  It would have been much simpler to understand if you'd asked that question directly :).  The answer is no, there's no way to do that.  You can obviously list specific files that should be considered not modified with the `-o` option, but you have to list them all directly.  There's no option which is effectively the opposite of the `-B` flag which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the first sentences of my question were clear enough... I'll try to be more practical in the future!